# JavaScript RegExp all chracters except dynamic series

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I'm working on an opensource project as a way to expand my knowledge of JavaScript, and created an utility that processes strings dynamically, and replaces specific occurrences with other strings.

An example of this would be the following:

> `jdhfkjhs${c1}kdfjh$%^%$S654sgdsjh${c20}SUYTDRF^%$&*#(Y`

And assuming I select the character '#', the RegExp processes it to be:

> `########${c1}####################${c20}###############`

The problem I am facing is my RegExp `/[^\$\{c\d\}]/g` is also matching any of the characters inside of the RegExp, so a string such as `_,met$$$$$1234{}cccgg.` will be returned as `#####$$$$$1234{}ccc###`

Is there a way I can catch such a dynamic group with JavaScript, or should I find an alternative way to achieve what I am doing?

---

For some context, the project code can be found [here](https://github.com/flynnham/js-ascii/blob/master/render.js).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may match the group and capture it to restore later, and just match any char (with `.` if no line breaks are expected or with `[^]` /  `[\s\S]`):

```js
var rx = /(\${c\d+})|./g;
var str = 'jdhfkjhs\${c1}kdfjh\$%^%\$S654sgdsjh\${c20}SUYTDRF^%\$&*#(Y';
var result = str.replace(rx, function ($0,$1) {
  return $1 ? $1 : '#';
});
console.log(result);
```

**Details**:

- `(\${c\d+})` - Group 1: a literal `${c` substring, then 1+ digits and a literal `}`
- `|` - or
- `.` - any char but a line break char (or any char if you use `[^]` or `[\s\S]`).

In the replacement, `$0` stands for the whole match, `$1` stands for the contents of the first capturing group. If the `$1` is set, it is re-inserted to the resulting string, else, the char is replaced with `#`.

Comment: I appreciate your help as well as your explanation! I will mention you in the resolution in the GitHub issue.